# Center buttons in grid in Android

Tags: android, button, grid

Is it possible to center auto added buttons in Grid view,bcs they always appear on left side no matter of gravity set

```
                button = new Button(context);
                button.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.buttonzagrid);
                button.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85,85));
                button.setPadding(8,8,8,8);
                button.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#332FA2"));
                button.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                button.setTextSize(18);
                button.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/FredokaOneRegular.ttf"));
                button.setBackgroundResource(bgpink);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you're doing in this Line of code

```
            button.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

is that you're setting the **button's** gravity to `CENTER` not the layout containing it.

For that you will need to specify your layoutParams .. something like this ..

```
GridLayout.LayoutParams lp = new GridLayout.LayoutParams;
lp.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
button.setLayoutParams(lp); // now you can add your button and it will be viewed correctly
```